# How do I use super in java?

Tags: java

```
public class A {

public void foo() {
System.out.println("A's foo");
    }
}



public class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
    System.out.print("B's foo");
    }
}



public  class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    A a= new B();
    a.foo();
  }
}
```

I want to use A's foo, what is the syntax for doing that? I tried `a.super.foo();`.

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the class know better than the caller what its foo method does?

Comment: The word super is used from inside the class. Not from the outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do so from within the class `B`. You won't be able to invoke `A`'s `foo` from outside `A` or `B` classes.

`A a= new B();` will always set the reference `a` to an instance of `B`. Thus, even though you cast it to `A`, at runtime the method that gets invoked is `B.foo`. That's runtime polymorphism.

Comment: So basically you're saying that I can't use A's foo by using instance of B as long as B class has a "foo" of itself?

Comment: Yes. As long as `B` overrides `A.foo`, you can't invoke `A.foo` by using an instance of `B`.

Answer (score 2):

I am really uneasy about a design that needs to do this kind of thing. If you want the object to behave like an `A`, why did you create a `B`?

You cannot use `super` from the outside of the class. Assuming you *really*, *really* need this (but I really doubt you can't find a better way) the best you can do about it is to expose a method that does this call to the outside:

```
public class B extends A {
    public void super_foo() {
        super.foo();
    }
    public void foo() {
        System.out.print("B's foo");
    }
}

public  class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a= new B();
        a.super_foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is it

```
    public class A {

    public void foo() {
    System.out.println("A's foo");
        }
    }



    public class B extends A {
        public void foo() {
        super.foo();
        System.out.print("B's foo");
        }
    }



public  class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    A a= new B();
    a.foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought you want to print both.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve will work if the method is static. [Non virtual methods in java](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article-print749.html)

```
public class A {
    public static void foo() {
        System.out.println("A's foo");
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public static void foo() {
        System.out.print("B's foo");
    }
}

public  class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       A a= new B();
       a.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it. The keyword is that it has been **overridden** by Java so it's no longer accessible.